# Invalid attempts to ssh my server, how do I prevent this?

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I have a mail server with ssh keypair auth. In the log file, I always notice these kinds of attempts to log in. Can anyone please explain what mistake I made?

```
     debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req winadj@putty.projects.tartarus.org
Jan 16 10:44:58 mail sshd[20519]: debug1: Forked child 18504.
Jan 16 10:44:58 mail sshd[18504]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Jan 16 10:44:58 mail sshd[18504]: debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe 6 sock 7
Jan 16 10:44:58 mail sshd[18504]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Jan 16 10:44:58 mail sshd[18504]: Connection from 211.222.177.29 port 58735 on 192.168.88.10 port 22
Jan 16 10:45:01 mail CRON[18510]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 16 10:45:01 mail CRON[18510]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 16 10:45:18 mail sshd[18504]: Did not receive identification string from 211.222.177.29
```

Comment: You are preventing it.  You can't literally prevent them from trying.  That's like attempting to get a cat to do something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Change default SSH port 22 to something else and such attempts will
  drop significantly.
- Install and configure `fail2ban` that will watch for such attempts and block subsequent attempts in firewall.
- You can also set IP range(s) in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` that allowed to access your SSH service by prepending public key with stanza "from" like that:
  `from="1.2.3.0/24,44.55.66.77" ssh-rsa ...key content...`

Comment: that's awesome guys thank you for your quick replies, just never been exposed to such attempts before and i'm new to ubuntu... does fail2ban affects my zimbra mail server? i know it needs to be configured but usually it should works smooth with it...  i guess adding IP range for public in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is the best for me... thank you all

Comment: `fail2ban` will not protect(read not affect) your mail services if you don't enable it(monitor specified ports/services) in the config of `fail2ban`, but I strongly advise you to use `fail2ban` for all publicly faced services, especially those ones that requiring authentication.

Comment: @G-Man Done. Linked to this post.